# Using join tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

Lets say I have two databases: one for students and one for classes.  I would like to be able to 'add' classes to a specific student and also be able to add students to a specific class.  I assume I need to use a join table here but I am a little lost on how to use them.  I would ultimately like to be able to do something like:

```
  @class.students.find(@student_id)
```

and this would tell me if the student is in the class or not.  I know the relationship between classes and students is 'has_many' and vice versa.  Does doing 't.references :students' in the migrate files accomplish that?  I tried adding that line to my migrate file and then tried finding something using the statement above and it gave me an error.  I am new to RoR so I am not even sure what the best way to go about achieving this is.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume you mean "Let's say I have two _tables_".  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is a many-to-many relationship (class has many students, student has many classes). For this you'll use a `has_many :through` relation. Take a look at the docs for [`ActiveRecord::Associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) (Ctrl-F for "Association Join Models").

In a migration, `t.references :students` is how you would specify a `belongs_to` relation, as it just adds a `student_id` column (which can only accommodate one id, i.e. one student). A join model, however, will have two columns: `student_id` and `class_id`. (Incidentally, calling a model 'Class' in Ruby is asking for trouble. Might I suggest 'Course'?)

Comment: Can you post the code for your Student, Class, and join models?

Answer (score 74):

Everything true what @Jordan said, here the concrete steps to take:

1. Create a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html): `rails g model CourseStudent` creates a join model for the n:m relation, and the migration to the corresponding table.
2. Edit the migration file `CreateCourseStudent` so it contains the following:

   ```
   class CreateCourseStudent < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :course_students do |t|

         # Your code comes here
         t.integer :student_id
         t.integer :course_id

         # Here comes the generated code 
         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Run the migration: `rake db:migrate`. As a result, the join table should now exist in your database.
4. Add to the models the following code

   ```
   class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :course_students
     has_many :students, :through => :course_students
   end

   class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :course_students
     has_many :courses, :through => :course_students
   end

   class CourseStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :student
     belongs_to :course
   end
   ```

You are now able to use the methods generated by the methods `belongs_to` and `has_many`:

- `@course.students`
- `@student.courses`

Try to find all the relevant facts and snippets in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html), there you should find all information you need to get on track. Good luck!

Comment: CourseStudent belongs_to should not be a symbol.

Comment: Vote up! Amazing! Helped me!

Comment: Newer versions of rails use this for the migration:

`t.integer :student_id`
`t.integer :course_id`

Comment: If you're using `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship you should also include in your migration `create_table` the argument `id: false`, because you're not representing a model with that table. If you wish to represent a model, then it's recommended that you use instead the `has_many through:` association.
You can also use `create_join_table` in your migration, that will not require of you to explicitly add the `id: false` argument. (As explained by StephanieS)

Answer (score 23):

This is an old question, but just in case anyone stumbles upon this like I did, you can now have the relationships `has_and_belongs_to_many`. So yes, you would create a join table:

```
create_join_table :students, :courses do |t|
  t.integer :student_id
  t.integer :course_id
end
```

And then in the models, you would say that a student `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses`
And a course `has_and_belongs_to_many :students`. There is no need to make a third class called CourseStudent. This [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has all this information

Comment: actually `create_join_table` automatically makes the two id fields for you... you can use the block for other fields, or for indexes

Comment: To go even further than @AlexChaffee, when I include those id specifications in the block, an error is raised. (I'm on Rails 6.) One doesn't need a block at all.