# ActiveRecord: Add foreign key after instance creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to a a foreign key "the rails way" after creation of an instance. How does it work?

Models:

```
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :letters
end

class Sender  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :letters
end
```

Code:

```
sender1 = Sender.first
letter1 = sender1.letters.create

#Now I want to add a connection from letter1 to a campaign, 
#but this cannot be the proper rails way:
letter1.campaign_id = 1
```

Comment: Sounds like you may want to set up a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).  The SO answer from @mleibelt [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606124/using-join-tables-in-ruby-on-rails?answertab=votes#tab-top) should also be helpful.

Comment: Initially, I did not want a has_many through association. But now I changed my mind. So in this case, problem is indirectly solved, thanks!