# Check if a conversation between two or more specific users already exists, where users-conversations have a HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

A user has and belongs to many conversations. A conversation has and belongs to many users and has many messages. A message belongs to a user and belongs to a conversation.

A very simple relationship model, initially working perfectly, but now giving me a headache as I refactor it to work for group messages, i.e. messages between more than two users.

I've only worked shallowly with HABTM associations before and can't figure out how to check if a conversation already exists between a given array of users. This check will happen in the conversations_controller, probably via a scope defined in the model. Edit: This check will probably only happen for conversations between two users. For example,

```
A conversation between User 1 and User 2 already exists.
User 1 sends a message to User 2 via the "Compose New Message" page.
The preexisting conversation is found and selected, and the new message is inserted into it.
```

versus

```
A conversation between User 1, User 2, and User 3 already exists.
User 1 sends a message to User 2 and User 3 via the "Compose New Message" page.
A new conversation is made, rather than searching for a pre-existing conversation.
```

models/conversation.rb

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  scope :between, -> users do
    uhhhhhhhhh???
    something like
    users.each do |u|
      then a where("conversations.user.id = ?").yadayadayada query
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/conversations_controller.rb

```
[snip]

def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:users]).present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:users]).first
  else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
  [snip lots of other stuff]
end
```

models/message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
end
```

db/migrate/create_messages.rb

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :conversation, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.boolean :read, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :messages
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_conversations.rb

```
class CreateConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :conversations do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.timestamps
    end
    end

  def down
    drop_table :conversations
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_conversations_users_join

```
class CreateConversationsUsersJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :conversations_users, id: false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :conversation, index: true
        t.belongs_to :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Update: Tried @DavidStosik's solution, but got the following NameError on the method scoped:

```
Started POST "/conversations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-10 16:53:51 -0400
Processing by ConversationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user_ids"=>"1 2"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `scoped' for #<Class:0x5afc2b8>):
  app/models/conversation.rb:25:in `block in <class:Conversation>'
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `user_time_zone'
```

Comment: Do you want conversations only between the users, or could the conversation also include others?

Comment: Only between those specific users.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between, ->(users) do
    base = all
    conditions = []
    users.each.with_index do |user, i|
      base = base
              .joins("JOIN conversations_users AS cu#{i} ON cu#{i}.conversation_id = conversations.id")

      cu_table = Arel::Table.new("cu#{i}")
      if condition
        condition = condition.and cu_table[:id].eq(user.id)
      else
        condition = cu_table[:id].eq(user.id)
      end
    end

    base.where(condition)      
  end
end
```

Selecting too many users at the same time will make the query huge, though.

Comment: You might be able to drop the joins to the users table there, and rely on the conversation_users table only, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting a NameError on the scoped method. I've added the backtrace to my original post, since comments don't preserve linebreaks, it looks like.

Comment: @KalynHorn Try `all` instead of `scoped`.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation which is relatively easy to code relies on selecting conversations for which three user-conversation join records exist where the user_ids are the ones you're interested in.

You really need access to the join table between users and conversations to make this efficient, but the logic would go something like:

```
Conversation.where(:id => 
  UserConversation.where(:user_id => [array of user ids]).
                   group(:conversation_id).
                   having("count(*) = ?", [array of user ids].size).
                   pluck(:conversation_id))
```

(not syntax checked)

Comment: Ahh! Looks like a very elegant solution. I've tried to investigate how to access join tables, but couldn't find a definitive answer. (Probably because it's simple.) Do I have to make a model for the table?

Comment: Update: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606124/using-join-tables-in-ruby-on-rails) explanation. If I use your method, would it be better for users-conversations to have a has_many :through relationship? I'm not quire sure what the difference is. (I shall continue to investigate.)

Comment: Double update: Ahh.... the problem with this is that things are getting written into the join table....... and then promptly deleted... and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yes, I think that has_many through would better support this. You could also use it for attributes relating to that user and conversation, like when they first joined it.