# Looking for a way to track history in rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, join

I'm considering this an add-on question of sorts to the thread below:
[Using join tables in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606124/using-join-tables-in-ruby-on-rails)

So we have 'Student' and 'Course' scaffolds joined by a many-to-many association, but in addition there is also a 'Semester' scaffold and what I wish to do is, for each student that is added to a course, for the application to search for previous iterations of the same course through past semesters, to that it's known how many times a student has taken that class before. I'm kind of mixed up at the moment as to how to implement this, so I was hoping someone could help me pin down the logic and code I should be operating by.

Some underlying assumptions I have so far:

- 'Course' and 'Semester' should, like 'Student' and 'Course', be joined
  by a many-to-many association (many courses are taught per semester,
  and a course is taught for more than one semester).
- There should be an action (let's say get_student) within the course
  controller to locate the student via student_id. **This would be the main area I'm scratching my head as to what to do. What would this method look like in code?**
- Within the student-course join table I should have an attribute
  'attempts' which increments each time get_student finds this
  student_id combined with the course_id that calls the method.This
  would be the mechanism that actually tells how many times the course
  had been attempted by the student.
- I initially wondered if there should be a 'semester' controller
  action to activate get_student across all semesters, but now I'm
  thinking that get_student should work fine without that.

Appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks.

Comment: So do you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good answer, just a **comment**.
I would comment, but hear will be more clear. I ll update for the other points. This is just an ongoing **feedback/discussion**, not an answer.

```
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :students
end
```

And
semester.courses[0].students => outputs the students array for that

This could be the method to calculate the number of student that did that course:

```
def studentForCourse

 #input_params.course_id => course id you are selecting

 semester = Semester.find(input_params)

 semester.courses.each do |course|
   if  course.id = input_params.course_id
     nstudents = course.students.size
   end
end
```